# Dependency management in obj-c: Can pods depend on each other?

Tags: dependencies, cocoapods

Let's say I install `AFIncrementalStore` pod using cocoapods, is there any way for `AFIncrementalStore` to specify that it depends on `AFNetworking`, which itself say depends on `ConciseKit`, so when I install AFIncrementalStore it ends up recursively go through the dependencies and installs all required pods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You do this through the [`dependency`](http://docs.cocoapods.org/specification.html#dependency) attribute in your podspec. Your example of AFIncrementalStore actually already does this [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/b15491c7f6ce1aa4785d0cb48f1705f5ef2f4443/AFIncrementalStore/0.5.0/AFIncrementalStore.podspec#L19-L21) with

```
s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '>= 1.0'
s.dependency 'InflectorKit'
s.dependency 'TransformerKit'
```

When you run `pod install` it analyzes these dependencies and installs their dependencies recursively as well. The issue arises with different versions of the same dependency. Currently CocoaPods cannot resolve linking to multiple versions of the same library. So if you included two libraries one that had a hard requirement of `AFNetworking` 1.0 and one that required 1.3.1 there would be an issue.

Comment: Ah, great example, thanks. Are there any workarounds for two pods having two different hard pinned dependency on a single library?

Comment: @Tony no there currently are not. I think this is because of the duplicate symbol issues with C based languages.